# button.BackgroundImage comparison

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compare a background image for buttons in an if statement, preferably a `Properties.Resourse.image`, however if need be, I can compare the background image of two buttons. The end goal is to see if the button has a background image of grey, and if it does I have an image that I want to change it with. Everything I've tried so far does not work.

First Try

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (var c in this.Controls)
    {
        var btn = c as Button;
        if (btn != null) btn.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Grey;
    }
 }

private void btnPlay1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btn00.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.Grey)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Is a valid move");
    }
 }
```

This didn't work so after doing some research I discovered the `.Equals()` function so I tried

```
if (btn00.BackgroundImage.Equals(Properties.Resources.Grey))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Is a valid move");
}
```

That didn't work so I tried seeing if it worked with other buttons

```
if (btn00.BackgroundImage.Equals(btn01.BackgroundImage))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Is a valid move");
}
```

However it only works when it is compared against itself

```
if (btn00.BackgroundImage.Equals(btn00.BackgroundImage))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Is a valid move");
}
```

I've also tried making just a plain variable and comparing that to the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that using `Properties.Resources` will create a new object each time, so even `Properties.Resources.Grey == Properties.Resources.Grey` would be `false`.  What you should do is go to `Properties.Resources` once per `Image` and assign the result to a field, then use that field repeatedly.  That way, there will be only one `Image` object and comparisons will work as expected.